# Can't upload files with zip format in Chrome using the accept attribute

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, file-upload

Dears,

I have Chrome version 60 and I need to know if there's something I'm doing wrong or if there's bug or there's something that I do not understand

Simply we're having a bug that our upload button (input type file) doesn't work sometimes
So when you click on the upload button it doesn't trigger the upload dialog

So I tried to isolate the problem to see what's going on and to be honest I'm not really sure why it is happening
 
 
Steps to reproduce the problem: 
 1. Create a new HTML file locally 
 2. Add this input type file in it

`<input type="file" accept=".csv,.tsv,.tab,.txt,.xlsx,.zip">`

 3. Run this file in Chrome

You should notice that this upload input doesn't work

Also if you tried and removed the zip extension it should work just fine

I'm aware that if I removed the whole accept attribute it should work fine but I want only to accept these files

So why is this happening ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you found any permanent solution...

Comment: No unfortunately :(

Answer (score 2):

We are also facing the same issue since yesterday. Though it was working fine before that. We tested these scripts in Firefox and Chrome Beta version and it worked fine over there. Looks like there is some problem with the recent update of Chrome. Looking for the permanent fix for this. But for the time being found some temporary solution:

accept=".zip,application/octet-stream,application/zip,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed"

Thanks, looking for a permanent solution.

Comment: We found a temporary solution by adding .gzip before the zip extension in the accept attribute :(
But I think of it as a workaround and not an actual fix

But now I think it's a bug in Chrome since you mentioned that you have the same problem